# Find the image of the set

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given set $$D=\{(x,y): x\geq -1, y-x\geq1, y+x\leq1\}$$ and the regular transformation $$\phi:\begin{cases}u=x^2+y^2\\v=x+y\end{cases}$$ How to find out the image of $D$, i.e. $\phi (D)$?

Comment: What does $D$ look like in $\Bbb{R}^2$?

Comment: It is triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$D$ is a triangle like you said in the comments, there are three sides. The first one is:
$$
l_1 = \{x=-1, 0\leq y\leq 2\}: r_1 = (-1,t), t\in [0,2]. 
$$
The second one is:
$$
l_2 = \{0\leq x\leq 1, y= 1-x\}: r_2 = (t,1-t), t\in [-1,0]. 
$$
The third one is:
$$
l_3 = \{-1\leq x\leq 0, y= 1+x\}: r_2 = (t,1+t), t\in [-1,0]. 
$$
Under $\phi$, $l^1$ is mapped to:
\begin{cases}u=(-1)^2+t^2,\\v=-1+t,\end{cases}
which is 
$$
u = 1 + (v+1)^2\quad \text{ for } v\in [-1,1].\tag{1}
$$
$l^2$ is mapped to
\begin{cases}u=t^2+(1-t)^2,\\v=1,\end{cases}
here $$u\in [1,5],\quad v = 1.\tag{2}$$
$l^3$ is mapped to
\begin{cases}u=t^2+(1+t)^2,\\v=1+2t,\end{cases}
this implies 
$$
u = \frac{v^2 +1}{2} \quad \text{ for } v\in [-1,1].\tag{3}
$$
In the $vu$-plane, $\phi(D)$ is the region bounded by (1), (2), and (3):
$$
\phi(D) = \{(v,u): v\in [-1,1], \frac{v^2 +1}{2}\leq u\leq v^2+2v+2\}.
$$